# UML to java translation

Tags: java, uml

I'm completely new to UML. How would this line be written in Java?

```
- obsArray: WeatherObservation[]
```

Comment: Maybe because this site uses markup which is explained right there above the window where you entered your question....

Comment: The other thing is;actually this site is for professionals and "enthusiastic amateurs". Whereas your question is super basic and could have been resolved with a small amount of research on your end. So even though you got an answer, don't let yourself be fooled into believing that this community is about questions such as your one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the largest online community for programmers to learn, share their knowledge, and advance their careers.

Comment: True. But that doesn't change anything about my comment, does it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a WeatherObservation array, you can write

```
WeatherObservation[] obsArray = new WeatherObservation[arraysize];
```

Or use **List** and **ArrayList**

```
List<WeatherObservation> obsArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming something like this

```
private WeatherObservation[] obsArray;
```

is what you're looking for.

Comment: The `-` explicitly tells, that it's 'private'.

Comment: @ThomasKilian That's good to know. I'll update my answer. My school's "version" of UML was pretty ill-defined haha

Comment: You forgot to take out the _The bits in_ part of your answer ;-)

Comment: I'm on a roll today.

Comment: And now you end up with pretty the same answer as the accepted one xD

Comment: You could make you answer more worthy by adding the private/public stuff as additional info. There are 4 chars for that,